# Does produce lose much of its nutrients just a few days after harvest?

Tags: nutrition, vegetables

[The Chicago Tribune](https://www.chicagotribune.com/dining/ct-xpm-2013-07-10-chi-most-produce-loses-30-percent-of-nutrients-three-days-after-harvest-20130710-story.html) has reported in 2013 that

> Most produce loses 30 percent of nutrients three days after harvest

I've seen an ad a few times recently that says "Produce loses most of its nutrients just a few days after harvest". I found this hard to believe and didn't know where to find an answer, except maybe here.

Does some produce loses ~1/3 of it nutrients shortly after harvest? 
If so, which?

Comment: Not to be too picky but it should be 'many of its nutrients' or else 'much of its nutrient value'. 'Many' is countable, quantifiable  ; 'much' is relative, indeterminate. [Stack Exchange - English Language](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31719). Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ: I am to blame for that wording, but I find it makes more sense to me

Answer (score 7):

The Chicago Tribune article references the following infographic from The Land Connection: https://www.thelandconnection.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/local_food_seasonal_calendar-health-benefits1.jpg

I've cropped the relevant section, here:
[image]

The quoted "Most produce loses 30 percent of nutrients three days after harvest" seems to refer to the text towards the bottom of that section, "Day 3. A majority of fresh vegetables have lost at least 1/3 of their nutrients."

The infographic has two sources listed in this section; Rich Pirog et al "Food, Fuel and Freeways" and IFR Extra Ltd. The [Food, Fuel and Freeways paper](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2014/ph240/pope1/docs/pirog.pdf) is solely about food miles, and makes no mention of nutritional value. I've found mention of the IFR research quoted in several newspaper articles; it ultimately seems to stem back to [a study they were commissioned to undertake by Birds Eye](https://marketinglaw.osborneclarke.com/retailing/did-frozen-veg-contain-30-more-vitamins-than-fresh/), the frozen food producers, to see if an earlier study, ["A comparison of the vitamin C content of fresh and frozen vegetables"
by D.J.Favell](https://ucanr.edu/datastoreFiles/608-97.pdf), (published in 1998 but written in 1996) was still relevant.

Looking at that study we can finally answer the question; the study was from the mid 90s, the only nutrient tested for was vitamin C, and the only vegetables tested were peas, UK; green
beans, Italy; spinach, Germany; broccoli, UK; and carrots, Austria. Looking at the graphs from the study:

[image]
[image]

We can see that the roughly 1/3 loss of vitamin C after three days seems accurate for the peas, beans and broccoli stored at ambient room temperature, though not for the chilled vegetables or the carrots. The vitamin C in the spinach did drop off a lot more sharply.

Comment: It's interesting that *The Land Connection*'s primary audience is local farmers, not consumers.

Comment: Looking good. But what about other nutrients except vitamin C?